# Trying to avoid duplicate query

Tags: sql

I have table A as
|name1|name2|value|

table B as |name|value|.

Here "name1" and "name2" attribute in table A are foreign keys referencing to the "name" in table B.

Now I want to have a query functions like this:

```
    SELECT value FROM A WHERE name1 IN 
    (SELECT name FROM B WHERE value = '1') AND 
    name2 IN (SELECT name FROM B WHERE value = '1')
```

Here the problem is if I do it like the code above, there will be two queries from table B. But in fact I only need one query, is there anything in SQL that writes as

```
    SELECT value FROM A WHERE name1,name2 IN (SELECT name FROM B WHERE value = '1')
```

And what if I want something like this:

```
    SELECT value FROM A WHERE name1,name2 IN 
   (SELECT name FROM B ORDER BY value DESC FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY)
```

?

Comment: what database system you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Could do it with a join?

`select value from A inner join table b b1 on a.name1 = b1.name inner join table b b2 on a.name2 = b2.name where b1.name = '1' and b2.name = '1'`

Comment: My problem here is that A and B are both very large, if I can select from B first, there will be much fewer tuples, would join here still impact the performance?

Comment: Does it have to be a pure query? Could you wrap it in a function or procedure? In that case, you could declare a temp table, and join against that? `declare @tbl table (name nvarchar); insert into @tbl select top 200 name from B; select name from A where name1 in (select name from @tbl) and name2 in (select name from @tbl)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use joins like this `SELECT A.value FROM A inner join B on A.name1 = B.name inner join B on A.name2 = B.name where B.name in ('1')` ?

Comment: My problem here is that A and B are both very large, if I can select from B first, there will be much fewer tuples, would join here still impact the performance?

Comment: I think joins are faster than multilevel query you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, value from b
left outer join (select name1 from a where value = '1') as a1 on 
a1.name1 = b.name
left outer join (select name2 from a where value = '1') as a2 on 
a2.name2 = b.name
where value is not null
/*omit null from left outer join for names not in table b*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer2005+ you can use option with [NOT EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) + [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operators

```
 SELECT A.value 
 FROM A 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (                   
                   SELECT A.name1
                   UNION
                   SELECT A.name2                   
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT B.name
                   FROM B 
                   WHERE B.value = '1'                 
                   )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/640d9/2)

Answer (score 0):

Create a view on table B and use it?

```
Create view B_LIMITED AS SELECT name FROM B WHERE value = '1'

select value from A inner join table b_limited b1 on a.name1 = b1.name inner join table b_limited b2 on a.name2 = b2.name where b1.name = '1' and b2.name = '1'
```